# Sql to LINQ query LINQ Query convert

Tags: entity-framework

I have a **SQL** query I want to write in **LINQ**

Here is my Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM [IHQDB].[dbo].[Table1] as t1 
inner join Table2 as t2 on t2.Table2 =t1.ChangedItemID 
inner join Table3 as t3 on t3.Table3 = t1.FromUserID 
where (t1.FromUserID=1 And t2.ContentItemID= t1.ChangedItemID) 
OR (t2.LastModifiedBy=1 or t2.CreatedBy=1 )
```

---

Hi now its working fine but My query little bit different  on place of 1 I need my **userID** on base of their First Name and Last Name from **M_User** table.
How can I get **UserId** on Base of **First Name + Last Name**.

Here is my **LINQ CODE** For Retrieving User Name

```
linq4 = from q in context.T_ContentItems
join p in context.M_Users on q.CreatedBy equals p.UserID 
where (advanceKeyword.Contains(p.EmployeeFirstName + " " + p.EmployeeLastName)) select q; 
advancechk12 = linq4.ToList();
```

========================================================================

What I require is that wherever I have written the value "1" (e.g. `t2.CreatedBy=1`), I need to find the **UserID**. For simplicity, I am able to get the names of all the filtered users in the **advancechk12**. How do I retrieve the **UserID's** of the list of usernames returned in **advancechk12**

Comment: Post your entity models as well.

Comment: Please ask your 2nd question on a new post.It's a new question.Then you'll have more feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace below mentioned Linq query with your models name.I just used the same name of the T-Sql.

```
 var t1List =   (from t1 in db.Table1
    join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.ChangedItemID equals t2.Id
    join t3 in db.Table3 on t3.Id equals t1.FromUserID
    where ((t1.FromUserID=1 && t2.ContentItemID= t1.ChangedItemID) || (t2.LastModifiedBy=1 or t2.CreatedBy=1))
    select t1).Distinct().ToList();
```